# Excessive downvotes

Tags: discussion, support, voting, down-votes

What can you do against excessive downvotes?

In the picture below the votes from today are shown.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for raising this as an issue. I've sent an email to Stack Exchange staff to see if we can get a quick resolution for you. In the mean time, please don't be discouraged! You're a great ELL answerer, as is obvious by the fact that you have only -23 from this downvoter, but +2073 from all of the rest of the ELL community :)

Comment: New here. Why would someone excessively down-vote answers or topics?

Comment: I have a feeling somebody targeted you for down-voting!

Comment: @EnglishLearner This sometimes happens when a user is angry with another user because of a comment or because they voted to close a question. Since a large number of downvotes can put a significant dent in a user's reputation, serial downvoting is sometimes used to get revenge. Voting in this manner is an abuse of power which is not tolerated. As you can see in this case, the downvotes were reversed and the downvoter was suspended.

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you have been serial downvoted. See *[What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)*. Here is an excerpt from the accepted answer there:

> 1. Do nothing. The daily vote anomaly script will pick it up and your rep will be recalculated automatically.
> 2. If after 36 hours (give the script time to run) you still see a problem, then flag one of your answers and ask a moderator to look into the anomalous voting patterns.
> 3. If it still hasn't been corrected, contact the SE team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page on the site.

Answer (score 12):

This has now been resolved:

> https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users/114/carlo-r
>
> +28    14 hours ago   reversal    Serial downvoting reversed

The downvotes have been removed and the offender has been given a temporary suspension for breaking the rules of Stack Exchange.

Hopefully this should be the end of the matter, and should serve as a reminder that serial downvoting isn't acceptable behaviour on ELL or any other Stack Exchange site.

If you have any further problems, please feel free to raise them via a different meta question, or by contacting any of the moderators or the Stack Exchange staff directly.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a user who serially down-voted you, then the script that detects such situations will automatically reverse the down-votes between 24 hours. If that doesn't happen, you can send a message to Stack Exchange staff, using the "contact us" link.

As for flagging one of your questions, as suggested in the other answer, keep in mind that moderators don't see who voted who; they are eventually alerted of specific irregular voting patterns. In any case, moderators cannot reverse the down-votes.

The serial down-votes have been reversed.

[image: screenshot]